# InfluxDB 2.0 with kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, telegraf

I am working with Influxdb version 2.0 and wanted to connect kafka consumer leagcy plugin with it. I wanted to know that how should I configure this configuration file of kafka consumer legacy and which path to place it on a server/local machine?

InfluxDB Sink Connector for Confluent Platform does not support for this version As came to know from the link below:

[Does Confluent's InfluxDB Sink Connector work with InfluxDB 2.0?](https://Does%20Confluent%27s%20InfluxDB%20Sink%20Connector%20work%20with%20InfluxDB%202.0?)

The configuration file for kafka consumer legaccy is given below:

```
# Read metrics from Kafka topic(s)
[[inputs.kafka_consumer]]
  ## topic(s) to consume
  topics = ["telegraf"]

  ## an array of Zookeeper connection strings
  zookeeper_peers = ["localhost:2181"]

  ## Zookeeper Chroot
  zookeeper_chroot = ""

  ## the name of the consumer group
  consumer_group = "telegraf_metrics_consumers"

  ## Offset (must be either "oldest" or "newest")
  offset = "oldest"

  ## Data format to consume.
  ## Each data format has its own unique set of configuration options, read
  ## more about them here:
  ## https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/DATA_FORMATS_INPUT.md
  data_format = "influx"

  ## Maximum length of a message to consume, in bytes (default 0/unlimited);
  ## larger messages are dropped
  max_message_len = 65536
```

Comment: Were you able to get the answer working?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using Kafka < 0.8, you should use the [new consumer plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/release-1.19/plugins/inputs/kafka_consumer/README.md), but the legacy one would be configured similarly in the config file.

That being said, Telegraf is a standalone process, not related to running Influx, which can be ran by

```
telegraf --config your_config.conf
```

You would use the corresponding [Influx 2.0 output plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/release-1.19/plugins/outputs/influxdb_v2/README.md) if you want to write to that version